# JSDOM returns an empty element

Tags: javascript, jsdom

Here is the snippet

```
let thtml = "<html><body><div id=app><div id=viewer></div></div></body></html>"
jsdom.env({
  html: thtml ,       
  done: function(err: any, window: any) {
   console.log(window.document.getElementById("viewer")); 
  }
});
```

Here `window.document.getElementById("viewer")` returns an empty `HTMLDivElement`. 
In Chrome, I got div `id="viewer"` the expectation is it should return the same div element.

Is it a bug or am I missing something here?

Comment: Its not very clear what your question is, really. Since we cant see the code for the div with id viewer anywhere.

Comment: it can be any html. window.document.getElementByTagName(div) returns HTMLDivElement, instead of div element. Also, the HTMlDIVElement is {}.see if that helps.

Comment: I have edited the question with more generic HTML. the console.log returns only HTMLDIVElement {}, instead of <div id = "viewer">

Comment: Where you using jsdom with some testing framework like Jest? I have this issue with Jest. But it worked with Jasmine.

Comment: Having exact same issue here, looking for a solution still, figured I'd post this comment in case anyone else went here too.

Comment: Having same question here as well.

Comment: Same for me. I'm using it with jest. Anyone out there have an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The element returned by jsdom is empty by design: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1891#issuecomment-345889214

What you should be doing is to use the DOM APIs to manipulate the returned object.